# Time failure when assigning a promise value to a global value in angular with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a problem when I call getProyectos () since it pulls the variable this.students when it has no value yet and i get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: alumnos is not iterable
TypeError: alumnos is not iterable
    at AdminpanelComponent.getProyectos (adminpanel.component.ts:300)
    at AdminpanelComponent.<anonymous> (adminpanel.component.ts:244)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at tslib.es6.js:73
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:876)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:69)
    at AdminpanelComponent.ngOnInit (adminpanel.component.ts:220)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31910)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:879)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:69)
    at AdminpanelComponent.ngOnInit (adminpanel.component.ts:220)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31910)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AdminpanelComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
```

This is the code of ngOninit ()

```
ngOnInit () {
     this.getAlumnos ();
    
     this.alumnosProyectos = this.getProyectos ();}
```

This is the code of getAlumnos() and getProyectos()

```
async getAlumnos() {
    await this.firestoreService.getUsuarios().subscribe((UsuariosSnapshot) => {
      this.alumnos = [];
      UsuariosSnapshot.forEach((alumnoData: any) => {
        if (alumnoData.payload.doc.data().rol == "Alumno") {
          this.alumno = {
            usuario: {
              id: null,
              data: null
            }
          };
          this.alumno.usuario.id = alumnoData.payload.doc.id;
          this.alumno.usuario.data = alumnoData.payload.doc.data();
          this.alumnos.push(this.alumno);
        }

      })


    });

  }
```

```
getProyectos() {
    let proyectos = []

    for (let alumno of this.alumnos) {
      let query2 =this.firestoreService.getProyectosUsuario(alumno.usuario.id).subscribe((usuario) => {
        if (usuario.length > 0) {
          proyectos.push({
            id: alumno.usuario.id,
            data: usuario[0].payload.doc.data()
          });
        }

      });

    }
    console.log("aqui", proyectos);
    return proyectos;

  }
```

Also attached is the firebase service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirestoreService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
public getUsuarios() {
    return this.firestore.collection('alumnos').snapshotChanges();

  }

public getProyectosUsuario(documentId: string){
    return this.firestore.collection('alumnos').doc(documentId).collection('proyectos').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

I would greatly appreciate your response, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can warp both of your functions inside another function and use the await keyword, to wait for your getAlumnos() function to finish before proceeding.
Hi have rewritten you code, so I should work.

```
        ngOnInit () {
         this.SomeFunctionName()
    }
    async getAlumnos() {
 this.alumnos = [];
    await this.firestoreService.getUsuarios().subscribe((UsuariosSnapshot) => {
      UsuariosSnapshot.forEach((alumnoData: any) => {
      console.log('alumno',alumnoData.payload.doc.data())
        if (alumnoData.payload.doc.data().rol == "Alumno") {
          const alumno = {
            usuario: {
              id: null,
              data: null
            }
          };
          alumno.usuario.id = alumnoData.payload.doc.id;
          alumno.usuario.data = alumnoData.payload.doc.data();
          this.alumnos.push(this.alumno);
        }
      })
      return this.alumnos;
    });
  }

    getProyectos() {
        let proyectos = []

        for (let alumno of this.alumnos) {
          let query2 =this.firestoreService.getProyectosUsuario(alumno.usuario.id).subscribe((usuario) => {
            if (usuario.length > 0) {
              proyectos.push({
                id: alumno.usuario.id,
                data: usuario[0].payload.doc.data()
              });
            }

          });

        }
        console.log("aqui", proyectos);
        this.alumnosProyecto = proyectos;

      }

      async SomeFunctionName(){

      await getAlumnos();
      getProyectos();

      }
```

Another way to solve this, is wrapping everything inside a pipe, so the functions are executed sequentially, but since you use async await, it´s eaiser to do as I just demonstrated.

UPDATED Solution

Here is and example on how to solve it using SwitchMap

```
SomeFunctionName() {
    this.alumnos = [];
    this.firestoreService.getUsuarios().pipe(switchMap((UsuariosSnapshot: any) => {
        UsuariosSnapshot.forEach((alumnoData: any) => {
            //console.log('alumno', alumnoData.payload.doc.data())
            //if (alumnoData.payload.doc.data().rol == "Alumno") {
            const alumno = {
                usuario: {
                    id: null,
                    data: null
                }
            };
            alumno.usuario.id = alumnoData.payload.doc.id;
            alumno.usuario.data = alumnoData.payload.doc.data();
            this.alumnos.push(alumno);
            //}
        })
        return of(this.alumnos);
    })).subscribe(alumnos => {
        let proyectos = []

        this.alumnos.forEach(alumno => {
            let query2 = this.firestoreService.getProyectosUsuario(alumno.usuario.id).subscribe((usuario) => {
                if (usuario.length > 0) {
                    proyectos.push({
                        id: alumno.usuario.id,
                        data: usuario[0].payload.doc.data()
                    });
                }

            });

        })
        console.log("aqui", proyectos);
        this.alumnosProyectos = proyectos;
    })

}
```

Remember to add these two line to your imports

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, in your modification inside the ngOnInit () only the call to the function that includes the other two goes, the rest goes outside right?

Comment: Hello friend, I'm sorry to tell you that the app keeps throwing the same error

Comment: Have you copy pasted everything ?

Comment: Can you make a console.log in the beginning of the getProyectos  and see what is inside of "this.alumnos"

Comment: yes i have tried putting a console log at the start of getProyectos () and it says this.alumnos is undefined

Comment: I update my answer, copy paste it all again.
I changed the function  "getAlumnos", to use local variable instead of global values.
Could you provide the console log for the function

Comment: your console log launches each student correctly because it is within the promise, but the console log of the start of getProjects says that this.students is an array [undefined, undefined, ...] with length = 0

Comment: Okay. Are you sure that the students are added to the array "this. alumnos"?

Comment: Could you make a https://stackblitz.com/ of your issue.
It´s easier to help you that way

Comment: Of course, the local alumno is added to the array this.alumnos. Now the console.log at the beginning of getProyectos is     console.log(this.alumnos,this.alumnos.length);
and throws: length=0 and the array with all of alumno {alumno 1, alumno 2, etc} but since the length is 0 it cannot be processed in getProyectos

Comment: Okay. 
Then try to remove the async keyword from getAlumnos and instead write return where you wrote await

Comment: it is the same result in console.log, you can view the actual code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5c994j and you can modify this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You did not setup you stack blish up right.
you can make a stack blish based on your github.
you just have to remember to remove credentials

Comment: Yes i know, but my app connect to firebase. I can´t do this. Can you help me without stackblitz? Please can you help me with another solution?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you without trying the code.
I can only help you if you make a stackblitz.
You can just remove your firebase key.

Comment: Hello again friend, i update my stackblitz, but i don´t know how to blish up right, can you help  to me? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5c994j thanks  a lot

Comment: Yes sure. follow the link.
https://stackblitz.com/docs#import-from-github

You should make a make a new public repository with your project, and remove all api keys and sensitive information

Comment: Perfect!
I will test it and come back to you tomorrow. It's getting late in Europe

Comment: It´s fixed. It worked when you used the third solution which I suggested

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Hello friend!! i have opened other issue. Can you help to me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61694254/how-to-delete-a-complete-collection-on-angular-crud-firebase thanks in advance