# How to delete a complete collection on angular crud firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase

I need to remove a complete collection in an angular crud firebase application.

I found this in the firebase documentation, but I don't know how to implement it: [firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections](http://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the doc:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

Comment: Hello friend, I have already seen that, but I don't know where to put each function, could you help me?
  a greeting

Comment: Have a look at the Get Started doc for Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started. The solution consists in having a Callable Cloud Function that you call from your Angular front-end.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to take a while looking at this, I did not know of its existence, if I have doubts I ask you, thank you again

Comment: Hello friend, i have learned the get started doc, but when i develop the solution for this issue, i take this error error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase_tools'.

50     return firebase_tools.firestore

Comment: Hi Again Joserto97.
I think we need some samtale code to help you

Comment: The thing Renaud linked is how to delete a collection using a cloud functions. Do you know what a cloud function is ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase with this video reference,
Please check the detail video

https://youtu.be/Ao4sdagqpvg

https://github.com/ankitkm418/ducktale